# Connection to storage server failed ldap roundcube

Tags: postfix, ldap, ubuntu-14.04, dovecot, roundcube

I cannot for the life of me figure out why I get this error "Connection to storage server failed".
It happens when an account with virtual mailbox stored in /home/vmail has a specified home folder in windows AD.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Dovecot Wiki](https://wiki2.dovecot.org/UserDatabase/ExtraFields) had my answer.

You can override the ldap query for home folder and hard code it with : 
user_attrs = homeDirectory= *whatever you would like the home/mail folder to be*

Inside: "/etc/dovecot/dovecot-ldap.conf"